# PHP DateTime Object error when passing variable in constructor

Tags: php, datetime

I searched SO for this but couldn't find any similar.

```
<?php
  $ref_date = $day['Date'];     // $ref_date is picked up from an array
  echo $ref_date;               // prints "250314" so data is correct
  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmy', $ref_date);
  var_dump($date);              // result FALSE
  echo $date->format('Y-m-d');  // Fatal error since $date not created
?>
```

if I substitute $ref_date by "250314" everything is OK:

```
<?php
   $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmy', "250314"); // DateTime Object created
?>
```

Tried to typecast $ref_date. (string)$ref_date.
PHP 5.3.27 || Timezone set.

I must be missing something very obvious?

Comment: What does `var_dump($ref_date);` show you?

Comment: Are you sure `$ref_date` is just `250314`, that is, doesn't contain any additional (unprintable) characters?

Comment: Are you sure that $ref_date is a string?

Comment: http://3v4l.org/EYZHI proves that your problem is something else than you are describing to us here.

Comment: @AnotherTest. Thanks, indeed I didn't notice there was a trailing space after the string. I removed that and now it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused due to trailing space in the string.
Echoing the string does not reveal this:

```
<?php
 echo $ref_date;    // 250314
?>
```

Vardumping the array from which the date was extracted revealed the trainling space:

```
<?php
  $ref_date = $day['Date'];  // $ref_date is picked up from an array
  var_dump($day)             // ["Date"]=> string(7) "260314 "
  // remove trailing space:
  $ref_date = rtrim($day['Date'];
  // now DateTime Object created!
?>
```

Thanks a lot for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this code:

```
//$day['Date'] = '250314'; //this is only for test.
$ref_date  = (int)$day['Date'];
if($ref_date>0){
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmy', $ref_date);
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
} else {
    echo '$day[Date] is bad value';
}
```